# Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700) (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting an error when opening Eclipse:

> Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.

I made sure there is a line in the Windows host file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host` that contain the line `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

I went to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS and set the local debugger port to "8601", checked the box `Use ADBHOST`, and the value set to "127.0.0.1".

However, none of these things fixed my problem.

I'm using Windows 10 64bit and Eclipse mars.

Answer (score 0):

You have not told DDMS which VM you want to debug at localhost:8700, go to the DDMS perspective and click on the system_process